# How to create plugin for browser like Flash or Java?

Tags: flash, plugins, browser

I know there is a question about that, but there isn't any good answer(for me).
I want to create a plugin like Flash.
What programming language do I need??
Are there any tutorials??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what browser you're targeting.  For IE plugins, you want to look into ActiveX, and you'd most likely be writing in C++, VB, or C#.  For Firefox plugins, you want to look into XUL and XPCOM, and you'll probably be writing in a combination of XML, JavaScript, and (optionally) C.

Comment: So for other browsers I need other languages??
What a mess.
I have one question: in what language is Flash(for Firefox)??